# resample dataframe into first 4 months of each year and sum the values

Tags: pandas

I wish to do soemthing like per mentioned on my title which is to first extract 4 months from each year and then sum the values of the first 4 months of each year.

my attemp:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'ds': [d for d in pd.date_range(start='2018-01-01', end='2020-05-30')],
             'value': [1 for v in range(881)]})
a.resample('Y', on='ds', loffset='4M').sum()
```

My current output:

```
    value
ds  
2019-04-30  365
2020-04-30  365
2021-04-30  151
```

My expected output:

```
    value
ds  
2018-04-30  120
2019-04-30  120
2020-04-30  121
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter first 4 moths before `resample` by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.dt.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month.html) and [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) for `less` like `5`, also for starting by `2018` is used `YS` for start of year:

```
df = a[a['ds'].dt.month.lt(5)].resample('YS', on='ds', loffset='4M').sum()
print (df)
            value
ds               
2018-04-30    120
2019-04-30    120
2020-04-30    121
```

Comment: thank you so much sir! Can I know what does the lt stands for?

Comment: Got it, lesser than it means.

Comment: Can I know sir, why is it starting from 2019 and not 2018? my data is only until 2020 but it shows 2021

Comment: @Anony - Because is used `loffset`, it move datetimes to next 4 months, if omit is get last date of year `df = a[a['ds'].dt.month.lt(5)].resample('Y', on='ds').sum()`

Comment: is there a way to make it the same like my expected output to show from year 2018-2020 only?

Comment: if you dont mind, could you also share the rules documentation link so that I could refer and learn from it? Like for 'YS'

Comment: @Anony - Check [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases)